# Ruby: Breaking from an Inline Block

Tags: ruby, block, break, macruby, pathname

### Update

*Ignore the following. It turned out to be a bug restricted to Macruby 0.10 and probably specific to my install. I'll leave the post in case anyone else hits the problem.*

---

I seemed to misunderstood something about ruby blocks. I wanted to use the `Pathname` or `Find` module's `find` to locate a specific file within a specific directory tree. However, I cannot get the block provided to `find` to return any value.

Since this:

```
n= (1..10).each {|i| break i if i > 5} 
puts "n = #{n}" #=> n=6
```

... works (and is a common construction) I expected that either:

```
starting_directory= #... a directory path
file_name_I_want_to_find= #... a file name e.g. my_file.txt
pd=Pathname.new(starting_directory)
path=pd.find{|p| break p if p.basename.to_s==file_name_I_want_to_find } 
puts "path = #{path}" #=> path =
```

... or:

```
path=Find.find(starting_directory) {|p| break p if p.include?(file_name_I_want_to_find) } 
puts "path = #{path}" #=> path =
```

... would produce just the one sought path but neither produces a value at all.

I know my test works because both of the following:

```
pd.find{|p| puts p if p.basename.to_s==file_name_I_want_to_find } 
#=> /path/to/file_name_I_want_to_find

Find.find(starting_directory) {|p| puts p if p.include?(file_name_I_want_to_find) } 
#=> /path/to/file_name_I_want_to_find
```

... work as expected.

Why doesn't `break` with `find` work the way it does in the first example?

More generally, am I using the correct ruby technique/idiom for this circumstance?

Comment: it works for me on ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 on windows.

Comment: breaking works on ruby-1.8.7-p334 on OSX for me as well.

Comment: @xinit -- Thanks I didn't think to check for a ruby version issue. I was running the script under macruby and macruby seems to be the cause. If you open a question, I'll accept it.

Comment: you can close your question if you want.

Comment: @edgerunner -- I might but I wanted xinit to get some well deserved rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that using `break` works on ruby-1.8.7-p334 (MRI) on OSX, as well as JRuby-1.6.1.

Comment: Turns out to be a bug with Macruby 0.10 only,

Answer (score 2):

`Enumerable#find` will do its own loop termination when the block returns "not false", so:

```
pd.find { |p| p.basename.to_s == file_name_I_want_to_find }
```

Regardless of whether your construct actually works or not (it seems to) you don't actually know which method ended up yielding control to the block, so I think it may be difficult to use break and continue to force behavior on core API elements. I suspect their use as block control flow expressions is intended mainly within an implementation rather than over API boundaries.

So, *"no",* that's not really the best Ruby idiom. You should use the API directly. Everything you are trying to do has a direct core API (and sort-of functional) realization without constructing your own imperative implementation.